# GPIO general use pins stuck in HIGH position

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I am trying to do "LED Blink" with GPIO and Python on my RPi B+.

I am using my breakout board with a breadboard and am jumping pin 11 (GPIO 17) > resistor > LED > jump to pin 9 (GND). I am using the latest version of `RPi.GPIO`.

Here's my python script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
# blinking function
def blink(pin):
        GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(1)
        GPIO.output(pin,GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(1)
        return
# to use Raspberry Pi board pin numbers
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
# set up GPIO output channel
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
# blink GPIO17 50 times
for i in range(0,50):
        blink(11)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Even before it runs, the LED is on. The script does not turn the LED off or on when run as sudo, and it gives me:

```
blink.py:13: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway. Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)
```

Images of my wiring:
[image: wiring overview]
[image: wiring closeup]

<strike>Then the script executes without further error, but the LED stays on. What is happening? Can I reset GPIO? How do I fix this?</strike>

The script still will not turn on the LED. Why not?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code, that suggests a wiring problem.  Could you add a photo of your set up to your post?

Comment: @joan I added a picture of my circuit. Excuse the mess.

Comment: Is the ribbon cable connected the wrong way around?  If you have a meter check the voltages between 3V3 and ground (3V3) and 5V and ground (5V).

Comment: It kind of looks like you actually have GPIO 27 -> resistor -> LED -> GPIO 17, although that might be the viewing angle.  The red stripe on that cable should be aligned with the corner of the pi (where the 3.3 and 5 V pins are), with the cable itself facing outward, i.e., not so that it crosses over the board.  They're made to work with cases that have a port in the side.

Comment: @goldilocks I changed the ribbon cable so that it was facing the right way (red on the corner, red next to 5v on the breakout board). The viewing angle makes the wiring look weird. I edited my post again with better pictures.

Comment: So now the problem is *"will not turn on the LED"*, correct?  I think using the ribbon backward means before you were using pin 12 as GND and the GND on one side of 12 as pin 17.  Probably not a big deal (except you weren't controlling them), but you may want to [test the pins](http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/pin-test/) anyway (there may be better ways to do this than that link, I don't know).

Comment: Is the pin definitely on high, rather than just unassigned? I know I was a bit confused the first time I tried to blink an led that it lit (albeit dull) before the code ran.

Comment: It turns out the LED was in backwards. I looked at my LEDs and the lead lengths were backwards. The long was - and the short was +.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the OP in a comment:

> It turns out the LED was in backwards. I looked at my LEDs and the lead lengths were backwards. The long was - and the short was +. –

Problems of this sort have three possible causes; this was evidently the second one:

- Incorrect code.  Beware that there are several different numbering schemes used to refer to the GPIO pins.  If you are working with example code, make sure it follows the same scheme you are.
- Incorrect wiring (backward component, inverted ribbon cable, etc.)
- Broken hardware.

Once you rule out the first two, you are stuck with the third option.  If you recognize you've made a mistake with one of the first two, beware that you may have created the third problem in the process.  You can permanently damage the GPIO system through incorrect use.